# Dictate moment of plot created in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Following code creates some plots in a for loop:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
b = [6,5,4,3,2,1]

for n in range(7):
    dflist = []
    df = pd.DataFrame(l)
    dflist.append(df)
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(b)
    dflist.append(df2)
    df = pd.concat(dflist, axis = 1)
    ax = plt.subplot(4, 2, n + 1)
    df.plot(ax=ax)
```

[image]

In the context of writing a larger program, is there a way to process the plot but show it later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always create a function, and store a lambda of it.

Say you define the function:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_it(l, b):
    for n in range(7):
        dflist = []
        df = pd.DataFrame(l)
        dflist.append(df)
        df2 = pd.DataFrame(b)
        dflist.append(df2)
        df = pd.concat(dflist, axis = 1)
        ax = plt.subplot(4, 2, n + 1)
        df.plot(ax=ax)
```

Now you have the data:

l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
   b = [6,5,4,3,2,1]

If you call `plot_it(l, b)`, it will plot things. You want to prepare the plot, but not plot it just yet. Just assign a lambda:

```
my_plot = lambda : plot_it(l, b)
```

When you want to actually plot, use:

```
my_plot()
```

Comment: Lambda doesn't seem to work. Neither does plot_it. What library is plot_it from?

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov Great. If there's some mistake, though, please feel free to LMK and I'll correct it.